# Gatsby ReactJS importing CSS from modules infinite loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, mdbreact

Currently I'm trying to start a new Gatsby ReactJS project.

The page loads without the use of CSS. But as soon as I enter css **external** CSS files in `gatsby-browser.js` the page has **infinite loading** and just displays a blank white screen.

(CSS imported from modules - importing these files has always worked with pure ReactJS.)

*gatsby-browser.js*

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css";
```

*versions*

```
"react": "^4.14.1",
"mdbreact": "^4.27.0",
"gatsby": "^2.24.63",
```

*my basic gatsby config*

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-sass",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
  ],
};
```

I did try to remove one at a time and it seems like I can only load in `bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css` without failing.

Any idea why this is happening?

Best regards, Chris

Comment: Did you try removing one by one each `import` in the `gatsby-browser.js` to check if one module is corrupted?

Comment: I did, yes. I can use only bootstrap without the application failing. The official MDB documentation and other projects use this exact configuration too though, and theirs seems to work.

Comment: Did you removed your global styles in the `Layout` component? Check: https://mdbootstrap.com/articles/react/gatsby-mdb-react-quick-start-quide/